# what is the difference between a proxy server like tor and a proxy tool like paros?

Tags: proxy, tor

it seems to be a big difference between them but eventually, both of them use a proxy
but paros can modify an intercept HTTP and HTTPS request , and tor just "make me invisible" ?

how does it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Paros and Tor serve different purposes. The first is a vulnerability scanner which might take your input, modify it and send it to the target website. Tor on the other side doesn't modify your requests, but wraps around encryption layers and send the requests over some servers until it reaches the target.

If you have Paros installed locally and send your requests through the software, the target website will see your IP address. Tor's purpose is to hide your IP address. So the target website will see some other address than your.

For specific [questions on Paros](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=paros) you might want to have a look at [security.SE site](https://security.stackexchange.com/). Questions about Tor are handled at [tor.SE](https://tor.stackexchange.com/).